# Modifying Regular expression to also match .java and .mm files

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am trying to use the [cscope-indexer](http://www.opensource.apple.com/darwinsource/Current/cscope-13/cscope/contrib/xcscope/) script. But I want to know how to change the following to include `*.mm` and `*.java` files?

```
egrep -i '\.([chly](xx|pp)*|cc|hh)$' | \
sed -e '/\/CVS\//d' -e '/\/RCS\//d' -e 's/^\.\///' | \
sort > $LIST_FILE
```

I tried

```
egrep -i '\.([chly](xx|pp)*|cc|hh|mm|java)$'
```

it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
egrep -i '\.([chly](xx|pp)*|cc|hh|mm|java)$' | \
sed -e '/\/CVS\//d' -e '/\/RCS\//d' -e 's/^\.\///' | \
sort > $LIST_FILE
```

Comment: I have tried adding 'mm|java' to egrep. It does not work. I get cscope no source files found.

Comment: Perhaps cscope can't parse java or '.mm' files?

Answer (score 0):

When you saw [chly] in the original regex, that meant "either a 'c', an 'h', an 'l', or a 'y'. When changed it to "chly*", it now meant "chl" followed by any number of y's. Also, when you removed the '\' from in front of the first period, you changed it's meaning from "match a period" to "match one of any character".

For more information on regexes, check out the [Perl Regular Expression Guide](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlre.html), since Perl pretty much invented regular expressions.

Comment: No, Perl definitely did not invent regular expressions.  The guide is nice, though.

Comment: No +1 for the patently false statement "Perl pretty much invented regular expressions".